# run binance-api-node module

Tags: javascript, node-modules, binance

I used npm to install the Binance API node. I reach to the following step:

```
import Binance from 'binance-api-node'

const client = Binance()

// Authenticated client, can make signed calls
const client2 = Binance({
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  apiSecret: 'xxx',
  getTime: xxx, // time generator function, optional, defaults to () => Date.now()
})

client.time().then(time => console.log(time))
```

Could you please guide me on how to run this part. The node module could be found on https://github.com/Ashlar/binance-api-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to create your API key following [this doc](https://binance.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002502072-How-to-create-API)

2. Once you have your API key and secret key, you store in `apiKey` and `apiSecret` respectively.
3. If you do not have an appropriate babel config, you will need to use the basic `commonjs` requires.
`const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default` instead of `ES6 import`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, just to clarify my question, how to run binace-api-model? is it through cmd or through html page? any keywords or guide to guide me in this matter. This is the first time for me to use node js module :)

Comment: Could you elaborate more details about the errors you've encountered to?

Comment: I just learned about commonjs and ES6. Sorry this comment is outside of my posted question. I have been trying to connect to Binance user api, I am trying to use the code I post without using the node js modul which is call binance-api-node, is there way to do that?